# Issue with Angular 4 + AOT + Firebasestore

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I am stuck on this error.On angularfire2 and am newbie can fix it

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { FirebaseAppConfig } from './';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
export declare const FirebaseAppConfigToken: InjectionToken<FirebaseAppConfig>;
export declare class FirebaseApp implements firebase.app.App {
    name: string;
    options: {};
    auth: () => firebase.auth.Auth;
    database: () => firebase.database.Database;
    messaging: () => firebase.messaging.Messaging;
    storage: () => firebase.storage.Storage;
    delete: () => Promise<any>;
    firestore: () => firebase.firestore.Firestore;
}
export declare function _firebaseAppFactory(config: FirebaseAppConfig, appName?: string): FirebaseApp;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the tour to see how the site works and what questions are on topic here, and edit your question accordingly. See also: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to AngularFire 5.0 and you'll have access to Firestore.